# Normalization of Graph

Tags: normalization

I have a Radial Distribution Graph (having x-axis ie.,[r], y-axis ie., [g(r)] values).

One of the values in the graph has g(r) high value which is around 45 and the rest have around less than 5. Hence it makes the graphs unclear to differentiate.
Since the values are high in this case, I need to normalize it.

How can i normalize the values (the y-axis [g(r)])?

I have attached the graph for visualization.[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see the `rdf` connection here.

Comment: I have the x and y values for the graphs. I just wanted to show in terms of the graph. But how can i normalize the y-axis value?